# airflow http callback sensor

Tags: callback, airflow

Our airflow implementation sends out http requests to get services to do tasks. We want those services to let airflow know when they complete their task, so we are sending a callback url to the service which they will call when their task is complete. I can't seem to find a callback sensor, however. How do people handle this normally?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no such thing as a callback or webhook sensor in Airflow.  The sensor definition follows as taken from the documentation:

> Sensors are a certain type of operator that will keep running until a certain criterion is met. Examples include a specific file landing in HDFS or S3, a partition appearing in Hive, or a specific time of the day. Sensors are derived from BaseSensorOperator and run a poke method at a specified poke_interval until it returns True.

This means that a sensor is an operator that performs **polling** behavior on external systems.  In that sense, your external services should have a way of keeping state for each executed task - either internally or externally - so that a polling sensor can check on that state.

This way you can use for example the [airflow.operators.HttpSensor](https://airflow.apache.org/code.html#airflow.operators.HttpSensor) that polls an HTTP endpoint until a condition is met.  Or even better, write your own custom sensor that gives you the opportunity to do more complex processing and keep state.

Otherwise, if the service outputs data in a storage system you can use a sensor that polls a database for example. I believe you get the idea.

I'm attaching a custom operator example that I've written for integrating with the Apache Livy API.  The sensor does two things: a) submits a Spark job through the REST API and b) waits for the job to be completed.

The operator extends the **SimpleHttpOperator** and at the same time implements the **HttpSensor** thus combining both functionalities.

```
class LivyBatchOperator(SimpleHttpOperator):
"""
Submits a new Spark batch job through
the Apache Livy REST API.

"""

template_fields = ('args',)
ui_color = '#f4a460'

@apply_defaults
def __init__(self,
             name,
             className,
             file,
             executorMemory='1g',
             driverMemory='512m',
             driverCores=1,
             executorCores=1,
             numExecutors=1,
             args=[],
             conf={},
             timeout=120,
             http_conn_id='apache_livy',
             *arguments, **kwargs):
    """
    If xcom_push is True, response of an HTTP request will also
    be pushed to an XCom.
    """
    super(LivyBatchOperator, self).__init__(
        endpoint='batches', *arguments, **kwargs)

    self.http_conn_id = http_conn_id
    self.method = 'POST'
    self.endpoint = 'batches'
    self.name = name
    self.className = className
    self.file = file
    self.executorMemory = executorMemory
    self.driverMemory = driverMemory
    self.driverCores = driverCores
    self.executorCores = executorCores
    self.numExecutors = numExecutors
    self.args = args
    self.conf = conf
    self.timeout = timeout
    self.poke_interval = 10

def execute(self, context):
    """
    Executes the task
    """

    payload = {
        "name": self.name,
        "className": self.className,
        "executorMemory": self.executorMemory,
        "driverMemory": self.driverMemory,
        "driverCores": self.driverCores,
        "executorCores": self.executorCores,
        "numExecutors": self.numExecutors,
        "file": self.file,
        "args": self.args,
        "conf": self.conf
    }
    print payload
    headers = {
        'X-Requested-By': 'airflow',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }

    http = HttpHook(self.method, http_conn_id=self.http_conn_id)

    self.log.info("Submitting batch through Apache Livy API")

    response = http.run(self.endpoint,
                        json.dumps(payload),
                        headers,
                        self.extra_options)

    # parse the JSON response
    obj = json.loads(response.content)

    # get the new batch Id
    self.batch_id = obj['id']

    log.info('Batch successfully submitted with Id %s', self.batch_id)

    # start polling the batch status
    started_at = datetime.utcnow()
    while not self.poke(context):
        if (datetime.utcnow() - started_at).total_seconds() > self.timeout:
            raise AirflowSensorTimeout('Snap. Time is OUT.')

        sleep(self.poke_interval)

    self.log.info("Batch %s has finished", self.batch_id)

def poke(self, context):
    '''
    Function that the sensors defined while deriving this class should
    override.
    '''

    http = HttpHook(method='GET', http_conn_id=self.http_conn_id)

    self.log.info("Calling Apache Livy API to get batch status")

    # call the API endpoint
    endpoint = 'batches/' + str(self.batch_id)
    response = http.run(endpoint)

    # parse the JSON response
    obj = json.loads(response.content)

    # get the current state of the batch
    state = obj['state']

    # check the batch state
    if (state == 'starting') or (state == 'running'):
        # if state is 'starting' or 'running'
        # signal a new polling cycle
        self.log.info('Batch %s has not finished yet (%s)',
                      self.batch_id, state)
        return False
    elif state == 'success':
        # if state is 'success' exit
        return True
    else:
        # for all other states
        # raise an exception and
        # terminate the task
        raise AirflowException(
            'Batch ' + str(self.batch_id) + ' failed (' + state + ')')
```

Hope this will help you a bit.

Comment: Thanks for this interesting answer spilio. I am looking into integrating spark jobs with airflow using livy. I was thinking in the exact same grounds, and today I found your answer. But I haven't tried it yet. Can you tell me something about your experiences with airflow/livy/spark stack? Did you find any major issues as I see livy development progress is not so rapid? Is livy already stable enough for your requirement? To be honest, I am very new to livy but had been using airflow for other than spark purposes since some time. Any reply of yours will be of great help. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Srikanth.  My experience with Apache Livy so far has been super smooth since it encapsulates the job submission tasks through its very simple to use REST API.  Prior to using Livy I had to submit Spark jobs to the cluster using the standard CLI commands, which required the Spark binaries to be available on the client machine.  As I am using the Hortonworks Data platform adding Livy to the cluster takes just one click through Ambari.  On top of that it can apply any security elements configured in the cluster.

Comment: Also, submitting a job through Livy is async by nature allowing you to have non-blocking Airflow tasks.  This is really useful since you can have different types of operators waiting for the job completion - either a submit / poll operator like the one I shared that does both jobs or poll-only operators that waits for the job to finish and then carry on with other tasks.  This can provide your flows with new dynamics and decouple things in very useful ways.  Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable inputs spilio. It really helps in taking decision in favour of airflow+livy+spark.

Comment: Thanks @spilio. It is really helpful.

Comment: I know its late, @xrysanthos is there anyway we can execute hive query with livy?

Comment: @yahoo it's never too late to ask :)  Livy is a service interacting with a Spark cluster by definition.  Hence, the only thing you can execute is Spark jobs.  That means you cannot execute a Hive query directly, but you can execute a query through a Spark job which makes sense anyways.